# Vaadin Leaflet Map layers icon remove

Tags: java, leaflet, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm using [V-Leaflet](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/v-leaflet) in the Java project I have:

```
    LMap leafletMap = new LMap();
    LOpenStreetMapLayer baseLayer = new LOpenStreetMapLayer(); 
    leafletMap.addBaseLayer(baseLayer, null);
```

The map appearance and functionality is fine

[image]

except the tiles icon at the upper-right corner. How to remove it??

I'm using Vaadin 8 with Java.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Extension extOut = null;
for(Extension ext : leafletMap.getExtensions()){
    if(ext instanceof LLayers){
        extOut = ext;                
    }
}
leafletMap.removeControl((AbstractControl)extOut);
```